# Sets of random numbers with no duplicates

Tags: swift, random

I want to write a program that can make random seats at my school in our diner.

I know this much

```swift
import Foundation

var randomNumbers: [Int] = []

for _ in 0...5 {
    let randomInt = Int.random(in: 0...160)
    randomNumbers.append(randomInt)
}

print(randomNumbers)
```

This prints 6 numbers between 1 and 160. I want to do this lets say 4 times. How would you make it so you can't sit together with people who you sat with before

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+random+number+no+repeat

Comment: Are you trying to seat everyone at tables of six and then trying to repeat this 3 times making sure no one sits at the same table with the same person twice?

Comment: yes @vacawama thats excatly what i want

Answer (score 0):

I'd create an array of numbers 1-160 and randomize them with the `shuffled` method. When you want to a subset of the random numbers, grab the last six, then remove the last six from the array. That way you wan't get any duplicates.

```
class RandomNumberGenerator {

    private var possible: [Int] = []

    init(range: ClosedRange<Int>) {
        reset(range: range)
    }

    func next(count: Int) -> [Int] {
        let result = possible.suffix(count).map { $0 }
        possible.removeLast(result.count)
        return result
    }

    func reset(range: ClosedRange<Int>) {
        possible = range.map { $0 }.shuffled()
    }

    private init() {}
}

let rando = RandomNumberGenerator(range: 1...160)
for _ in 0..<4 {
    print(rando.next(count: 6))
}
```

Note that the array will run out of numbers if you call it more than 26 times. So to restore all the values in the array simply call `reset`:

```
rando.reset(range: 1...160)
```